# invalid XML: no alias declared for namesapce <>; in Java

Tags: java, xml, minio

I'm trying to run an example using Java from this link:
[GetBucketNotification.java on GitHub](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/GetBucketNotification.java)

The source code is as follow:

```
import io.minio.MinioClient;
import io.minio.errors.MinioException;
import io.minio.messages.NotificationConfiguration;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class GetBucketNotification {

/**
 * MinioClient.getBucketNotification() example.
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, XmlPullParserException {
    try {
        /* minio config. */
        MinioClient minioClient = new MinioClient("http://localhost:9000", "accesskey",
                "secretkey");            

        NotificationConfiguration notificationConfiguration = minioClient.getBucketNotification("test");
        System.out.println(notificationConfiguration);
    } catch (MinioException e) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred: " + e);
    }
}
}
```

It's a simple Java program that returns the bucket notifications for a given bucket, from a Minio storage server. But when I run this program I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid XML: no alias declared for namesapce <>; work-around by setting XML namepace directly by calling the set method of com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:69)
at com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary.getNamespaceAliasForUriErrorOnUnknown(XmlNamespaceDictionary.java:312)
at com.google.api.client.xml.Xml.parseElementInternal(Xml.java:253)
at com.google.api.client.xml.Xml.parseElement(Xml.java:222)
at io.minio.messages.XmlEntity.parseXml(XmlEntity.java:65)
at io.minio.MinioClient.getBucketNotification(MinioClient.java:3656)
at GetBucketNotification.main(GetBucketNotification.java:26)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'd really appreciate any sort of help/suggestion to get it fixed.